# Rule at the middle of a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to draw a (dotted) horizontal rule at the middle of the page (same distance from the top as from the bottom) independent of the rest of the text (perhaps in some way overlayed over the text)?

I just want it as a help line for a special purpose, it will removed in the final version of the text so it doesn't matter if it overlays text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  color=blue,
  contents={\tikz\draw[ultra thick,dotted] (current page.west) -- (current page.east);}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To make the line disappear, you can simply change

```
\usepackage{background}
```

to

```
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
```